# Remove \Endif from algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I want to write the following algorithm in LaTeX.

[image: image of algorithmn]

The code I used is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\algtext*{EndIf}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Left-rotate $(T,x)$}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $y \gets \mathrm{right}[x]$
\STATE $ \mathrm{right}[x] \gets \mathrm{left}[y]$
\IF {$ \mathrm{left}[y] \neq \mathrm{NIL} $}
\STATE $ p[\mathrm{left}[y]] \gets x $
\ENDIF
\IF {$ p[x]=\mathrm{NIL} $}
\STATE $ \mathrm{root}[T] \gets y $
\ELSIF {$ x=\mathrm{left}[p[x]] $}
\STATE $ \mathrm{left}[p[x]] \gets y $
\ELSE 
\STATE $ \mathrm{right}[p[x]] \gets y $
\ENDIF
\STATE $ \mathrm{left}[y] \gets x $
\STATE $ p[x] \gets x $
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I have already tried all the solutions on this platform but unfortunately, none worked. The output generated is the following:

[image: result]

I do not want the `\ENDIF`, it would be nice if `then` can be on the line below the one with `\IF`, and the nesting should be according to the first image. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add package option `noend` to `algorithmic`:

```
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\algtext*{EndIf}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Left-rotate $(T,x)$}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $y \gets \mathrm{right}[x]$
\STATE $ \mathrm{right}[x] \gets \mathrm{left}[y]$
\IF {$ \mathrm{left}[y] \neq \mathrm{NIL} $}
  \STATE $ p[\mathrm{left}[y]] \gets x $
\ENDIF
\IF {$ p[x]=\mathrm{NIL} $}
  \STATE $ \mathrm{root}[T] \gets y $
\ELSIF {$ x=\mathrm{left}[p[x]] $}
    \STATE $ \mathrm{left}[p[x]] \gets y $
  \ELSE 
    \STATE $ \mathrm{right}[p[x]] \gets y $
\ENDIF
\STATE $ \mathrm{left}[y] \gets x $
\STATE $ p[x] \gets x $
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: result]

I personaly would prefer the version with end marks, the algorithm is better readable ...

Comment: Thank you. Can you also have the indentation as required (for `\ELSE` after the `\ELSIF`)?

Comment: And can I also send 'then' to the next line?